# How to add a custom error message in Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, node-modules

I have created a server application where it can serve dynamic pages depending on the path.
Simply, this checks if the path number provided is a prime number or not...
For example,
`localhost:3000/isprime/7` -------> The input parameter 7 is a prime number
`localhost:3000/isprime/36` -------> The input parameter 36 is not a prime number

The problem is, how can I create an error handler to display an error message if letters are entered into the address instead of digits.
For example,
`localhost:3000/isprime/four`

I have very limited knowledge of error handling in the express. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here's my code so far,

```
    app.get('/isprime/:inputNumber(\\d+)', function(request, response) {
    let num =parseInt(request.params.inputNumber);
  
    function isPrime(num) 
    {
    for(var i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
    return num > 1; 
    }

    if(isPrime(num))
    {
      var p = '<span style="color:blue;">IS a prime number.</span>';
    }
    else
    {
      var p = '<span style="color:red;">IS NOT a prime number.</span>';
    }
  
    let html = ''; 
    html += '<h1>Prime Number Check</h1>'; 
    html += '<p>The input parameter <b> ' + num +'</b>....'+ p+ '</p>';
  
    response.send(html); 
    });
```

Comment: Add `if (num === NaN) return false;` to the first line of your isPrime function

Answer (score 1):

The `(\\d+)` that you're putting at the end of your route definition makes it so that only parameters with 1 or more digits will match the route.

If you remove that, and then `isNaN()` to test if the parameter value parses to an integer, you will be able to pick out the requests you want and send a response to requests with parameter values that are only letters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use isNaN(), isNaN() gives a boolean if the number is valid otherwise returns false,

Here is example for your code

```js
app.get('/isprime/:inputNumber(\\d+)', function(request, response) {
    let num = parseInt(request.params.inputNumber);
    if(isNaN(num)) {
     response.send("<h1>Invalid number</h1>");
     return; 
    }
    function isPrime(num) {
        for (var i = 2; i < num; i++)
            if (num % i === 0) return false;
        return num > 1;
    }

    if (isPrime(num)) {
        var p = '<span style="color:blue;">IS a prime number.</span>';
    } else {
        var p = '<span style="color:red;">IS NOT a prime number.</span>';
    }

    let html = '';
    html += '<h1>Prime Number Check</h1>';
    html += '<p>The input parameter <b> ' + num + '</b>....' + p + '</p>';

    response.send(html);
});
```

Comment: I need to create an error handle using express to display the error message. But I have tried your solution, and it still doesn't work giving an error "Cannot GET /isprime/a".